# how can a CSS :active class be added to an <a>nchor when referred to by clicking a link from outside the page?

Tags: html, css, anchor

i know that in-page DOM tools like javascript and CSS can be used to add :active classes to links that have been clicked, or objects referred to by a clicked link, but is there any way to have an :active class added to an object which has been clicked/referred to from a link outside the current page?

i know if i `<a href="#anchor">` i can then add an onClick handler in javascript to add the :active class to the #anchor, but how can i accomplish the same thing when https://example.com/#anchor is clicked from outside the page?

Comment: Are you talking about adding an `.active` class or an `:active` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)? Because I don’t know of any way to add pseudo-classes programmatically. If you did mean `.active` instead of `:active`, please edit your question.

Comment: i am looking for a pseudo-class yes, i would like to link directly to a specific row of a table and have something happen to that table when a link directly to that row is visited from outside of the same page

Comment: The basic method for doing anything like this would be to add query string parameters to your external links and then parse the query string with Javascript when your page loads, taking whatever actions you like in response. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) and [this](https://medium.com/swlh/urlsearchparams-in-javascript-df524f705317).

Comment: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)surely ins't what you are looking for, because _"The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button."_ - and that is not the case here. Maybe you are looking for [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery 3.6.0

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
   var url = window.location.href;
   var anchorIndex = url.indexOf('#');
     if (anchorIndex !== -1) {
       var anchorId = url.substring(anchorIndex + 1);           
       $('#' + anchorId).addClass('active');
     }
});
```